# javascript uncaught reference error onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

Trying to call a javascript function with a button, and the button is not doing anything on click. The debugger returns "uncaught reference error: printNumber is not defined.

`printNumber` is the function I want to call.

I did a search and most people with this problem did not use the proper syntax for declaring their function, defined their function within another function (function out of scope), or put their functions after they are called. It turns out nothing in my head is running. I tried to put a prompt in it for example, and the prompt did not show up.

Here is my script:

```
    <head>
    <script type="javascript">
    var x=0;
    function addNumber(x){
        x = x + 1;
        return x;   
    }

    function printNumber(number){
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML=addNumber(number);
    }

    </script>
    </head>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <body>
<p><center><b>The number of times the button has been clicked is ... <b><p>
<br>
<div id="number"></div>
<br>
<form>
    <input type="button" id="StartButton" value="Click to add 1 to counter" onClick="printNumber(x)">
</form>
</center>
```

Can anybody point out to me where the problem is coming from? Thank you, this is for a programming class, and I hope that others who might also encounter this will see this.

Comment: 'uncaught reference error: printNumber is not defined.' is the expected error. What is `myFunction`?

Comment: yea that is the error, sorry i meant to reword the error so it would be more general

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dep5tzwg/ works fine. Can you post your complete HTML as single file.

Comment: thank you! I have my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `<script type="text/javascript">` and note that you can't increment `x` in the way you wanted. You are incrementing a local variable, not the global one.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var x=0;
        function addNumber(){
            x = x + 1;
            return x;   
        }
    
        function printNumber(number){
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML=addNumber();
        }
    
        </script>
        </head>    <body>
    <p><center><b>The number of times the button has been clicked is ... <b><p>
    <br>
    <div id="number"></div>
    <br>
    <form>
        <input type="button" id="StartButton" value="Click to add 1 to counter" onClick="printNumber()">
    </form>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you! I'll try to remember that (I have been copy-pasting the template for quite some time and I had to make this code for a quiz)

Comment: @Mr.Clefable Keep in mind that homework questions are generally not allowed on SO, although I think in this case, it is acceptable since you showed that you have tried something and can't figure it out. Just keep that in mind as you ask questions.